# STM32F405 usb recognition

Tags: usb, stm32

We've made an oscilloscope that displays data on PC screen with a software, which is created on Qt Creator. The MCU software works well on STM32F4 Discovery board, which has STM32F407VG; but when we program STM32F405RG, the program loads successfully, the device manager of Windows says "device not recognized", but Windows sees the device. We drew the pcb parts based on ST schematics.

What is the difference between 405RG and 407VG?
What may be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Can you use a USB analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

we have solved the problem; if anybody asks the same question here is the answer;
Keil creates the SystemInit function for every MCU you selected. Then we developed the software for STM32F407VG and we have configure the settings for it; after we selected MCU as STM32F405RG, we must reconfigure the settings for STM32F405RG.
thanks for the answer